# Find and replace all substrings in a string

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, .net

Given a list of strings `paragraphs` and `words`. Check each `paragraphs`'s item for containing `words`'s item as a substring. In the case of positive, replace all characters of this substring on 'x'.

I do it in the following way:

```
// In production, words.Length ~500
var words = new List<string>
{
    "technology",
    "word",
    "IBM",
    // ...
};

// In production, paragraphs.Length ~10,000 and paragraphs[i].Length ~200
var paragraphs = new List<string>
{
    "Microsoft Corporation is an American multinational technology corporation which produces computer software...",
    "Microsoft (the word being a portmanteau of \"microcomputer software\") was founded by Bill Gates and",
    "As of 2015, Microsoft is market-dominant in the IBM PC compatible operating system market and the office software",
    // ...
};

for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        var template = new string('x', word.Length);
        paragraphs[i] = paragraphs[i].Replace(word, template);
    }
}

foreach (string para in paragraphs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(para);
}
```

[image]

---

I think that using algorithms is very bad since there is much `String.Replace()` calling. As you know, the `string` type is immutable and each `String.Replace()` allocates a new space in memory.

Please, review my implementation and help to improve.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: This is generally called [redaction](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/redaction) just FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **StringBuilder**.

When adding `string`s into `StringBuilder` it allows you to work with their characters without adding extra allocations, and whenever you're done, you can call `ToString()` to get the immutable string representation of it.

`StringBuilder` is often used when there is some repetitive executions on string/s or when the string that is going to be manipulated has a large size.

So, your work can be changed to this :

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
    builder.Append(paragraphs[i]);
    
    for(int x = 0; x < words.Count; x++)
    {
        builder.Replace(words[x], new string('x', word[x].Length)); 
    }

    paragraphs[i] = builder.ToString();
    
    builder.Clear();
}
```